# create workflow in GCP and call google function without authorization

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

As the title says it all I have a function which is authorized and I want to call it from google cloud workflow but I don't want to pass authorization headers in the call.

I believe there are some modifications required in the IAM roles maybe or something like that can anyone help me out here.

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain more what you tested? What you observed? And what you want to fix?

Comment: I have resolved the issue and posted answer
Thanks for your response :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed the issue after doing some extensive RnD.

When we create a function which requires authorization in google cloud then after that we can define principle permission there is a permission Function Invoker which needs to be allowed to the user who is going to call that function from google cloud workflow.

There was just one thing needed to add in function call headers in google workflow which is

```
auth:
   type: OIDC
```

So by doing this we can avoid adding Authorization bearer token in google cloud workflow calls.

Hope this will help someone else in future.

Thanks